# Dockerized database passwords management

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, redis, docker, database-security

For example, I need to "dockerize" PostgreSQL, MongoDB and Redis each one to a separate container. I want to create a secure passwords-protected users/roles for that storages and then access them from a several dockerized applications. `Dockerfile`s are surely under the VCS and I won't keep any passwords there. Is there any best practices for managing passwords/credentials for dockerized systems?

Comment: env file, etcd, consul - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749899/hide-obfuscate-environmental-parameters-in-docker

Comment: Check out vault: https://vaultproject.io/. It has special added support or Postgres https://vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/postgresql/index.html

Answer (score 0):

After a while I found a good choice to keep/manage secret environment variables using the `now` tool, take a look: https://zeit.co/blog/environment-variables-secrets