# Populating Docker containers with sensitive information using kubernetes

Tags: security, docker, kubernetes, confd

I have a pod that runs containers which require access to sensitive information like API keys and DB passwords. Right now, these sensitive values are embedded in the controller definitions like so:

```
env:
- name: DB_PASSWORD
  value: password
```

which are then available inside the Docker container as the `$DB_PASSWORD` environment variable. All fairly easy.

But reading their documentation on [Secrets](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/secrets/), they explicitly say that putting sensitive configuration values into your definition breaches best practice and is potentially a security issue. The only other strategy I can think of is the following:

- create an OpenPGP key per user community or namespace
- use [crypt](https://github.com/xordataexchange/crypt) to set the configuration value into etcd (which is encrypted using the private key)
- create a kubernetes secret containing the private key, [like so](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/secrets/secret.yaml)
- associate that secret with the container (meaning that the private key will be accessible as a volume mount), [like so](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/secrets/secret-pod.yaml#L10-L17)
- when the container is launched, it will access the file inside the volume mount for the private key, and use it to decrypt the conf values returned from etcd
- this can then be incorporated into [confd](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd), which populates local files according to a template definition (such as Apache or WordPress config files)

This seems fairly complicated, but more secure and flexible, since the values will no longer be static and stored in plaintext.

So my question, and I know it's not an entirely objective one, is whether this is completely necessary or not? Only admins will be able to view and execute the RC definitions in the first place; so if somebody's breached the kubernetes master, you have other problems to worry about. The only benefit I see is that there's no danger of secrets being committed to the filesystem in plaintext...

Are there any other ways to populate Docker containers with secret information in a secure way?

Comment: @larsks But wouldn't the definition file for the secret then store the credentials in plaintext? Or in base64, which could be easily decoded.

Comment: Yeah, and I misread the fact that you were already taking advantage of that API. So, never mind...

Comment: As I understand it, Secrets is the way to pass sensitive information, but it has its limitations. Yet it's better than just passing sensitive info directly in ENV variables.

Comment: Re. "other ways": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749899/hide-obfuscate-environmental-parameters-in-docker

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have many megabytes of config, this system sounds unnecessarily complex. The intended usage is for you to just put each config into a secret, and the pods needing the config can mount that secret as a volume.

You can then use any of a variety of mechanisms to pass that config to your task, e.g. if it's environment variables `source secret/config.sh; ./mybinary` is a simple way.

I don't think you gain any extra security by storing a private key as a secret.

Comment: Well, here's why I'm not sure this is a good idea:
1. I think placing secrets in individual files a bit clunky, since it's not how most applications deal with sensitive data. You'd need to write boot-up extra logic, which is inconvenient. 
2. Mounting volume files and putting them in the env is too static. I'd rather have my app configuration stored dynamically in etcd, using `crypt` for encryption.
3. From a security POV, I think requiring extra time and knowledge for access is better than giving it to them in plaintext.

Comment: a Secret can only be 256 chars long... so works well for passwords and keys maybe, but not for things like certificates etc... that can be much longer.

Comment: A secret *key* can only be 256 chars; there's no limit on the secret *data*.

Comment: So as for hohner's points: 1: you have to write the start-up logic no matter what. 2: If you can change config without restarting your app, then yes, you probably want to manage that yourself; that's not the normal case. 3: you're always giving something in plaintext, whether it's the key or the data itself, directly.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally resolve to user a remote keymanager that your software could access across the net over a HTTPS connection.   For example [Keywhiz](https://square.github.io/keywhiz/)   or [Vault](https://vaultproject.io/) would probably fit the bill.

I would host the keymanager on a separate isolated subnet, and configure firewall to only allow access to ip addresses which I expected to need the keys.   Both KeyWhiz and Vault comes with an ACL mechanism, so you may not have to do anything with firewalls at all, but it does not hurt to consider it -- however the key here is to host the keymanager on a separate network, and possible even a separate hosting provider.

You local configuration file in the container would contain just the URL of the key service, and possible a credentials to retrieve the key from the keymanager -- the credentials would be useless to an attacker if he didn't match the ACL/IP addresses.