# How can I pass secret data to a container

Tags: security, docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

My Tomcat Container needs data that has to be well protected, i.e. **passwords** for database access and **certificates and keys** for Single Sign On to other systems.

I´ve seen some suggestions to use `-e` or `-env-file` to pass secret data to a container but this can be discovered with docker inspect (`-env-file` also shows all the properties of the file in docker inspect).

Another approach is to **link a data container** with the secrets to the service container but I don´t like the concept of having this data container in my registry (accessible for a broader range of people). I know I can set up a private registry, but I would need different registries for test and production and still everyone with access to the production registry could access the secret data.

I´m thinking about setting up my servers with a directory that contains the secret data and to **mount the secret data into my containers**. This would work nicely with test- and production servers having different secrets. But it creates a dependency of the containers to my specific servers.

So my question is: How do you handle secret data, what´s the best solution to that problem?

Comment: This has been discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749899/hide-obfuscate-environmental-parameters-in-docker

Comment: envvars are probably good enough: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70827/passing-secret-keys-securely-to-docker-containers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker and securing passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22651647/docker-and-securing-passwords)

Answer (score 4):

Update January 2017

Docker 1.13 now has the command [`docker secret`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/) with docker swarm.
See  also "[Why is `ARG` in a `DOCKERFILE` not recommended for passing secrets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33623649/6309)".

---

Original answer (Sept 2015)

The notion of `docker vault`, alluded to by  [Adrian Mouat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4332/adrian-mouat) in [his previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30756013/6309), was actively discussed in [issue 1030](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10310) (the discussion continues on [issues 13490](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13490#issuecomment-111662657)).

It was for now rejected as being out of scope for docker, but also included:

> We've come up with a simple solution to this problem: **A bash script that once executed through a single `RUN` command, downloads private keys from a local HTTP server, executes a given command and deletes the keys afterwards**.
>
> Since we do all of this in a single `RUN`, nothing gets cached in the image. Here is how it looks in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN ONVAULT npm install --unsafe-perm
```

> Our first implementation around this concept is available at [`dockito/vault`](https://github.com/dockito/vault).
>
> To develop images locally we use a custom development box that runs the Dockito Vault as a service.
>
> The only drawback is requiring the HTTP server running, so no Docker hub builds.

Comment: Upvoted for the update pointing to docker's secret management function.

Answer (score 0):

Mount the encrypted keys into container, then pass the password via pipe. The difficulty comes with the `detach` mode, which will hang while reading the pipe within the container. Here is a trick to work around:

```sh
cid=$(docker run -d -i alpine sh -c 'read A; echo "[$A]"; exec some-server')
docker exec -i $cid sh -c 'cat > /proc/1/fd/0' <<< _a_secret_
```

First, create the docker daemon with `-i` option, the command `read A` will hang waiting for the input from `/proc/1/fd/0`;
Then run the second docker command, reading the secret from stdin and redirect to the last hanging process.