# How to add private nuget source in dotnet dockerfile?

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, nuget, dockerfile

I try to add (override) a private nuget source to my build script in order to add the user/pw - and keep it out of my source control. What I tried so far:

- `nuget` is not recognized as command inside the image
- `dotnet nuget` does not have the command to add additional sources
- installing nuget does not effect `dotnet restore`

```sh
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nuget 
RUN nuget source Add -Name "Private Feed" -Source ".." -UserName "UserVAR" -Password "PassVAR"
RUN dotnet restore
```

Comment: if you ever upgrade 3.1 supports this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-add-source

Answer (score 13):

By adding a nuget.config to the solution/project and copying it into the Docker project:

```
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["nuget.config", ""]
```

You can add the source and then have success with your docker build.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="Nellson Nuget Repo" value="http://private.source.local:123/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="NuGet official package source" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="Nellson Nuget Repo" value="http://private.source.local:123/v3/index.json" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This worked but I'm getting unauthorized error in the build pipelines

Comment: Note regarding activePackageSource (2.x only; deprecated in 3.x+)

Answer (score 12):

My current workaround is to create a copy of the `nuget.config` with a `packageSourceCredentials` section that contains placeholders for user name and password. I then replace my existing `nuget.config` with this file and replace the user name and password with environment variables.

The only drawback is that I need to keep both config files in sync. If I modify my `nuget.config` in the project I need to remember to update the copy as well.

`nuget.config.template`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="GitHub private registry" value="https://nuget.pkg.github.com/your_orga/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <GitHub_x0020_private_x0020_registry>
        <add key="Username" value="USER" />
        <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="PW" />
    </GitHub_x0020_nuget_x0020_registry>
</packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-image
ARG NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN
ARG NUGET_USER_NAME

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./My.Project .

# Replace nuget.config
RUN rm nuget.config
COPY ./gitlab-ci/nuget.config.template ./nuget.config
RUN sed -i -e "s/USER/$NUGET_USER_NAME/g" -e "s/PW/$NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN/g" nuget.config

RUN dotnet restore
```

`.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
docker build
      --build-arg NUGET_USER_NAME=$NUGET_USER_NAME
      --build-arg NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN=$NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN
      --tag $CI_REGISTRY/organization/application:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
      --file gitlab-ci/Dockerfile
      .
```

Comment: With this approach your username and token will end up in the image. You should use docker secret for that purpose. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621242/why-is-arg-in-a-dockerfile-not-recommended-for-passing-secrets

Comment: You can't use docker secrets with stand-alone containers.

Comment: @Kamushek we use staged builds to prevent this: https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/

Comment: @jwillmer if I remember correctly, in staged builds your data will be accessible in history on building machine or smth

Answer (score 8):

Answer for year 2023

### Without security

This code for WebApplication3 works just fine. We use BaGet NuGet server to have a proxy between Nuget.org and our build servers for faster loads of common packages we use.

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication3/WebApplication3.csproj", "WebApplication3/"]

# !!!IMPORTANT PART HERE !!!

# Add your NuGet server here
RUN dotnet nuget add source https://nuget.yourdomain.com/v3/index.json
# For our purposes, to hide nuget.org behind a NuGet proxy we disable its source, you can skip that
RUN dotnet nuget disable source "nuget.org"

# Just to see if two lines above work
RUN dotnet nuget list source

RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication3/WebApplication3.csproj"

COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication3"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication3.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication3.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication3.dll"]
```

### With basic authentication

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build

# !!!IMPORTANT PART HERE !!!

ARG NUGET_USERNAME
ARG NUGET_PASSWORD

ENV NUGET_USERNAME=${NUGET_USERNAME}
ENV NUGET_PASSWORD=${NUGET_PASSWORD}

# Adds this source with basic authentication, other authentication types exist but I'm not sure if they are applicable here in Linux based container
RUN dotnet nuget add source https://nuget.yourdomain.com/v3/index.json --name="Your source name" --username ${NUGET_USERNAME} --valid-authentication-types basic --store-password-in-clear-text --password ${NUGET_PASSWORD}


WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication3/WebApplication3.csproj", "WebApplication3/"]

RUN dotnet nuget disable source "nuget.org"

# Just to see if two lines above work
RUN dotnet nuget list source

RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication3/WebApplication3.csproj"

COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication3"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication3.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication3.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication3.dll"]
```

Comment: Man, you are a life saver. I tried again and again with just ARG NUGET_USERNAME but it didnt work. I had no idea I had to get the arg into env first. Thanks!

Comment: I would appreciate, if you mark this as not useful, you told me why. :-))

Answer (score 6):

1. In your private feed if it's azure artifacts create a personal access token with full access.

   [image]
2. Add a NuGet.Config file to the root of your project

   ```xml
   <configuration>
     <packageSources>
       <add key="MyPrivateFeed" value="https://myfeed.url/index.json" />
     </packageSources>
     <packageSourceCredentials>
       <MyPrivateFeed>
         <add key="Username" value="myusername" />
         <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="xq6n4lvnayeo2f467osasdasdgj4nat7xw2mkm7qwowvqeutjdueq" />
         <add key="ValidAuthenticationTypes" value="basic" />
       </MyPrivateFeed>
     </packageSourceCredentials>
   </configuration>
   ```

   the ClearTextPassword key is your PAT
3. Add these two-line to the copy section of your docker file

   ```
   COPY "NuGet.Config" "/"
   RUN ["cp", "/NuGet.Config", "/root/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config"]
   ```

   and finally run your docker build it should be work.

Comment: That works but then you're committing credentials to your repo.

Comment: when you have private repo you have no choice.

Comment: You can at least restrict the PAT to read packages only.

Comment: That's not quite accurate. You can pass credentials to the Dockerfile via arguments
ARG password

Comment: The final two Docker instructions could be a single one (`COPY` to the correct directory directly, no need for `cp`), else an unnecessary layer is created.

Answer (score 3):

The `nuget source` command is part of the nuget.exe command line interface, which can only be used on Linux in combination with [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/runtime/). Because the mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk image is a Linux container (Debian, to be precise) - you will need to install Mono and Nuget yourself in order to use that command. Your other option is to get the [official Mono docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mono/) and install .NET Core and NuGet.exe into that.